# DateDiff with multiple events Same Column SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, datediff, recursive-query

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide. I am looking to get the date difference between events that are stored in the same column. Referring to the Sample data, I am looking for the differences between the "Partial Submissions" and their respective subsequent "Jr Reviewed" events.

referring to same data again, I need the dateDiff from

- 1st "Partial Review" to 1st "Jr Reviewed"
- 2nd "Partial Review" to 2nd "Jr Reviewed"
- 6th "Partial Review" to 3rd "Jr Reviewed"

I am not sure where to start, all i have done is add the rownumbers which are partitioned by "Descrip" and ordered by "Date" Asc. Any sort of guidance or method of accomplishing (Recursive CTE?) this would be greatly appreciated.

[Start End - 2 records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlBGX.png)

Comment: How do you order table? `IDX`? Which DBMS?

Comment: So what do your *expected results* look like?

Comment: Hey Neer, yes, these are ordered by IDX, I have been using the IDX as opposed to date because we have some timezone issues.

Comment: Neer - Microsoft Sql Server

Comment: Damien, I ultimately need the avg time between the events for each record number. Where there are multiple between, I will be using the first. IE 2nd Partial to 2nd Jr Reviewed event.

Comment: I have considered using the Rownumbers and Max/Min on multiple JOINS but number of rows are not uniform across records and I wouldnt know how many joins i need.

Comment: @NEER - Sorry i responded in the post and didnt tag you

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Sorry to you as well, I posted but didnt tag you.

Comment: @Takeo - don't try to just give us a narrative. Mock up another table that shows what the results would look like if you had your query working, and [edit] that into your question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sorry, hope that will add some clarity. That question alone got me thinking that i need to separate the events into two columns.

Comment: You use Sql 2012+?

Comment: @NEER yes, i use 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (RowNumber INT, RecordNumber INT, IDX INT, DESCRIP NVARCHAR(50), DATES DATETIME, EVENTNUM INT)
INSERT INTO @Tbl
VALUES  
(1, 11515,  13, 'Partial Submission', '8/12/16 00:21',  3078),
(1, 11515,  14, 'Junior Reviewed', '8/12/16 15:52',  3089),
(2, 11515,  26, 'Partial Submission', '8/18/16 15:24',  3078),
(3, 11515,  33, 'Partial Submission', '9/6/16 9:47',  3078),
(4, 11515,  34, 'Partial Submission', '9/6/16 9:47',  3078),
(5, 11515,  39, 'Partial Submission', '9/9/16 13:19',  3078),
(2, 11515,  40, 'Junior Reviewed', '9/11/16 8:30',  3089),
(6, 11515,  46, 'Partial Submission', '9/15/16 12:30',  3078),
(3, 11515,  54, 'Junior Reviewed', '9/17/16 10:01',  3089),
(7, 11515,  57, 'Full! Submission', '9/19/16 9:16',  3079),
(1, 11520,  19, 'Partial Submission', '8/20/16 00:42',  3078),
(1, 11520,  22, 'Junior Reviewed', '8/22/16 9:06',  3089),
(2, 11520,  28, 'Partial Submission', '8/29/16 20:12',  3078),
(2, 11520,  34, 'Junior Reviewed', '9/1/16 8:20',  3089),
(3, 11520,  38, 'Partial Submission', '9/8/16 15:03',  3078),
(4, 11520,  39, 'Partial Submission', '9/8/16 15:03',  3078),
(3, 11520,  47, 'Junior Reviewed', '9/14/16 13:53',  3089),
(5, 11520,  48, 'Full! Submission', '9/16/16 13:19',  3079),
(4, 11520,  52, 'Junior Reviewed', '9/17/16 10:51',  3089),
(6, 11520,  53, 'Full! Submission', '9/19/16 16:21',  3079)


;WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT 
      *, 
      RowId         = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY Recordnumber ORDER BY Recordnumber, IDX),
      RowIdByDescrip    = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Recordnumber, DESCRIP ORDER BY Recordnumber, IDX)
  FROM @tbl
)


,Test as 
(
    SELECT
        A.Recordnumber,
        A.DESCRIP,
        A.EVENTNUM,
        A.IDX, 
        A.DATES StartDate, 
        LEAD(A.DATES) OVER ( Partition BY A.Recordnumber ORDER BY A.IDX) EndDate,
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, A.DATES, LEAD(A.DATES) OVER (Partition BY A.Recordnumber ORDER BY A.IDX)) AS DateDifff
    FROM @tbl A INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT
                C.Recordnumber,
                MIN(C.IDX) AS IDX
            FROM 
       CTE C

            GROUP BY 
                C.RowId - C.RowIdByDescrip,
                C.DESCRIP,
                C.Recordnumber
       ) B ON A.IDX = B.IDX and A.Recordnumber = B.Recordnumber
    ) 

Select 
*
From Test
Where eventnum in ('3078')
order by Recordnumber, IDX
```

Comment: Yep! Thanks to you. Best part is I learned at least 2 new things. I had never used LEAD and had never subtracted in the GROUP BY. Thank you very much for sticking with this post and all of the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try as the below:

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (RowNumber INT, RecordNumber INT, IDX INT, DESCRIP NVARCHAR(50), DATES DATETIME, EVENTNUM INT)
INSERT INTO @Tbl
VALUES  
(1, 11515,  13, 'Partial Submission', '8/12/16 00:21',  3078),
(1, 11515,  14, 'Junior Reviewed', '8/12/16 15:52',  3089),
(2, 11515,  26, 'Partial Submission', '8/18/16 15:24',  3078),
(3, 11515,  33, 'Partial Submission', '9/6/16 9:47',  3078),
(4, 11515,  34, 'Partial Submission', '9/6/16 9:47',  3078),
(5, 11515,  39, 'Partial Submission', '9/9/16 13:19',  3078),
(2, 11515,  40, 'Junior Reviewed', '9/11/16 8:30',  3089),
(6, 11515,  46, 'Partial Submission', '9/15/16 12:30',  3078),
(3, 11515,  54, 'Junior Reviewed', '9/17/16 10:01',  3089),
(7, 11515,  57, 'Full! Submission', '9/19/16 9:16',  3079),
(1, 11520,  19, 'Partial Submission', '8/20/16 00:42',  3078),
(1, 11520,  22, 'Junior Reviewed', '8/22/16 9:06',  3089),
(2, 11520,  28, 'Partial Submission', '8/29/16 20:12',  3078),
(2, 11520,  34, 'Junior Reviewed', '9/1/16 8:20',  3089),
(3, 11520,  38, 'Partial Submission', '9/8/16 15:03',  3078),
(4, 11520,  39, 'Partial Submission', '9/8/16 15:03',  3078),
(3, 11520,  47, 'Junior Reviewed', '9/14/16 13:53',  3089),
(5, 11520,  48, 'Full! Submission', '9/16/16 13:19',  3079),
(4, 11520,  52, 'Junior Reviewed', '9/17/16 10:51',  3089),
(6, 11520,  53, 'Full! Submission', '9/19/16 16:21',  3079)


;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IDX) RowId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DESCRIP ORDER BY IDX) RowIdByDescrip
    FROM @Tbl
    WHERE
        EVENTNUM IN 
        (
            3078, --Partial Submission
            3089 -- Junior Reviewed
        )
), CTE2
AS
(
     SELECT
        MIN(C.IDX) AS IDX
    FROM 
        CTE C
    GROUP BY 
        C.RowId - C.RowIdByDescrip,
        C.DESCRIP
)

SELECT      
    R.RecordNumber,   
    R.IDX ,
    R.StartDate ,
    R.EndDate ,
    R.DateDifff
FROM
(
    SELECT
        A.EVENTNUM,
        A.RecordNumber,
        A.DESCRIP,
        A.IDX, 
        A.DATES StartDate, 
        LEAD(A.DATES) OVER (ORDER BY A.IDX) EndDate,
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, A.DATES, LEAD(A.DATES) OVER (ORDER BY A.IDX)) AS DateDifff
    FROM
        @Tbl A INNER JOIN 
        CTE2 B ON A.IDX = B.IDX
 ) R
 WHERE
    R.EVENTNUM = 3078 --Partial Submission
ORDER BY R.RecordNumber
```

Result:

```
RecordNumber IDX         StartDate          EndDate            DateDifff
------------ ----------- ----------------   ----------------   -----------
11515        13          2016-08-12 00:21   2016-08-12 15:52   15
11515        26          2016-08-18 15:24   2016-09-06 09:47   450
11515        34          2016-09-06 09:47   2016-09-01 08:20   -121
11515        46          2016-09-15 12:30   2016-09-14 13:53   -23
11520        38          2016-09-08 15:03   2016-09-11 08:30   65
11520        19          2016-08-20 00:42   2016-08-22 09:06   57
```

Comment: Will do, I just the tried the previous and it was very close but returned too many results i can edit my question with what i mean after i try the latest update from you.

Comment: Wow, thats awesome. It looks perfect. Thank you very much. I added in the record number as there are going to be multiple records but that shouldnt be an issue. For my own knowledge you used a CTE with multiple Sub queries in the join?

Comment: I used the CTE to facilitate readability. You can without CTE or you can use multiple cte.

Comment: Awesome, going to mark this as answered. I plan to break this down and figure out exactly what you did but if I happen to run into anything related to this would it be okay to contact you? If not, no problem, thank you for all of your help and the swift response.

Comment: Updated - I still consider this answered but i needed to add in more record numbers IE other transactions and the data became skewed. I tried adding in partitions by Record Number but it has not work thus far.

Comment: Show sample and expected data please

Comment: Just added another picture above showing what it is doing to the results. I was expecting the same results from record 11515 as in the top result set.

Comment: Could you show as first picture? This sampe is not clear.

Comment: Added another record to the original Data set, is that what you meant? Sorry should i done this from the beginning.

Comment: Is it same `Full Submission` and `Partial Submission`?

Comment: Hi Neer sorry for the delay in response it was 2:15 AM my time. They are both types of events that I would need datediffs from. We can treat them the same.

Comment: Hi @Neer - That did not produce the expected results. It works with 1 record but changes the data when adding more. I added a picture above for reference.

Comment: Hey @Neer thank you for the continued help. The recent results you posted when adding the next recorded changed the first record's (11515) results. I posted a picture of what the correct original results were when using only 1 record (11515) .  Adding the second record changes the 1st's results.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and I hope this helps. Each IDX is respective to the record number and is unique to the record number. The idx represents the overall order of events for each record number.

Comment: Can you show me `Start` and `End` in list like me please.

Comment: I updated the original post with a start/end picture. Hope this helps. I am working with the original answer to see if i can add some partitions to get it to work with both records. Greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Hmm I think we have sorting problem. How do you sort in your result picture?

Comment: I'm actually on here right now trying to post the altered answer, do I just indent 4 spaces in every line?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. Just too long for a comment.

I guess. I did not understand the question exactly. Let me tell you what i know.

Firstly, Sorting according to `IDX`

I just work between the two events, `Partial Submission` and `Junior Reviewed`

Result table: `Partial Submission Start` - `Junior Reviewed    END`

```
RowNumber   RecordNumber IDX         DESCRIP                                            DATES                       EVENTNUM    RowId                RowIdByDescrip
----------- ------------ ----------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------------------     ----------- -------------------- --------------------
1           11515        13          Partial Submission Start                           2016-08-12 00:21:00.000     3078        1                    1
1           11515        14          Junior Reviewed    END                             2016-08-12 15:52:00.000     3089        2                    1
1           11520        19          Partial Submission Start                           2016-08-20 00:42:00.000     3078        3                    2
1           11520        22          Junior Reviewed    END                             2016-08-22 09:06:00.000     3089        4                    2
2           11515        26          Partial Submission Start                           2016-08-18 15:24:00.000     3078        5                    3
2           11520        28          Partial Submission                                 2016-08-29 20:12:00.000     3078        6                    4
3           11515        33          Partial Submission                                 2016-09-06 09:47:00.000     3078        7                    5
4           11515        34          Partial Submission                                 2016-09-06 09:47:00.000     3078        8                    6
2           11520        34          Junior Reviewed    End                             2016-09-01 08:20:00.000     3089        9                    3
3           11520        38          Partial Submission Start                           2016-09-08 15:03:00.000     3078        10                   7
4           11520        39          Partial Submission                                 2016-09-08 15:03:00.000     3078        11                   8
5           11515        39          Partial Submission                                 2016-09-09 13:19:00.000     3078        12                   9
2           11515        40          Junior Reviewed     End                            2016-09-11 08:30:00.000     3089        13                   4
6           11515        46          Partial Submission  Start                          2016-09-15 12:30:00.000     3078        14                   10
3           11520        47          Junior Reviewed     End                            2016-09-14 13:53:00.000     3089        15                   5
4           11520        52          Junior Reviewed                                    2016-09-17 10:51:00.000     3089        16                   6
3           11515        54          Junior Reviewed                                    2016-09-17 10:01:00.000     3089        17                   7
```

Result:

```
RecordNumber IDX         StartDate          EndDate            DateDifff
------------ ----------- ----------------   ----------------   -----------
11515        13          2016-08-12 00:21   2016-08-12 15:52   15
11515        26          2016-08-18 15:24   2016-09-06 09:47   450
11515        34          2016-09-06 09:47   2016-09-01 08:20   -121
11515        46          2016-09-15 12:30   2016-09-14 13:53   -23
11520        38          2016-09-08 15:03   2016-09-11 08:30   65
11520        19          2016-08-20 00:42   2016-08-22 09:06   57
```